# Converse Support for IE

Tags: converse.js

My company has been using Inverse for quite sometime. I normally download it from Ignite, but now Inverse has been replaced with Converse.
The new version of Converse does not have IE support.

Is there a version out there that will work in Internet Explorer?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, version 3.3.4.

You can use the fullscreen version here: https://conversejs.org/3.3.4/inverse.html